# is there any way to convert dates in the long-format 'September 21, 2022' to just standard DD/MM/YYYY formats?

Tags: sql, postgresql

is there any way to convert dates in the long-format 'September 21, 2022' to just standard DD/MM/YYYY formats?

Comment: Another good example why date values should be stored in a `date` column, not a `varchar` column.

Comment: Dates have no format. So, if this value is stored in a proper date column, what you see may be the string your tool uses to represent the date. Usually, tools have some option to change this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `to_date()` to convert the string to a date:

```
to_date('September 21, 2022', 'Month dd, yyyy')
```

This returns a proper `date` value - the formatting depends on the SQL client displaying that value. If you just want to use it in your code, then keep it as a date. If you really do need to format that date back into a string (because e.g. your SQL client uses a format you don't like and can't change), then you can use `to_char()` on that result:

```
to_char(to_date('September 21, 2022', 'Month dd, yyyy'), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: that's perfect - worked like a charm!! The next part of my project is to group and count these by months, could you please offer some advice on how I could achieve this please?

Comment: Try the documentation: [Postgres date functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html). For group and count by month see  `extract()` , `date_part()`, or `date_trunc()` functions.

Answer (score -2):

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 103)
```

You can change the format by changing the number of the format you need , 103 or else .

Comment: This is neither standard SQL nor valid for Postgres